# What is the best software to split and join avi files?

Tags: windows, avi, video-editing

What is the best software to split and join avi files without losing quality (lossless) in Windows?

Comment: You might want to specify what platform you are after.

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/9048/what-is-the-best-software-to-split-and-join-avi-files

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Windows, [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) should be able to do this. Check out [this guide](http://www.dvd-guides.com/content/view/13/59/) for in-depth guide on how to split videos.

The creatively named [Easy Video Splitter](http://www.doeasier.org/splitter/help.html) can apparently do the job easier, but I have never used it so i would not know first hand.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows, you can use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/). On Linux, there is a very similar program called [AviDemux2](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)

Comment: And VirtualDub is an opensource product as well.

Comment: appears that AviDemux works on Windows, as well...

Answer (score 6):

Without a doubt, [VirtualDub](http://virtualdubmod.sourceforge.net/) is the way to go.

- Open the first AVi in VirtualDub
- Select "Direct Stream Copy" for both video and audio
- In the file menu, choose Append AVI Segment (or similarly named)
- File -> Save As and give your avi a new name

Bingo! I have done this many times. The only gotcha is to be aware that the dimensions, codecs, bitrates, etc. all need to be the same or your new video file will behave, lets say, strangely. Or not at all.

Answer (score 5):

What OS?

On linux, you can use [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html):

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -o output.avi input1.avi input2.avi
```

Comment: I'm using Windows Vista.

Comment: Then I would use VLC - http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Comment: I've been searching this command for ages!

Comment: mplayer/mencoder runs on windows from a long time :)

Answer (score 4):

For Windows: Virtualdub. No contest.

http://www.virtualdub.org/

Can do lossless splitting and joining to, which is very fast, by doing no re-enconding (but it can then only split on key-frames, obviously, and both parts joined must use the same encoding).

Comment: can it do re-encoding for splitting?

Comment: yes, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Quality after split is problem, because you must reencoded new file. But it depends on what coded used in AVI file.

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/)

- windows only

Comment: That is no problem if you use VirtualDub with "Direct stream copy" instead of "Full processing mode"

Comment: for me, direct stream copy still gives me between i-frames, but "smart rendering" (if another video codec is selected) gives the right sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this with the Quicktime player (you might need pro), but a lot of people don't like simply because the UI looks out of place on windows.

Answer (score 1):

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)

Answer (score 0):

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) is a very powerful and handy video editing software. It supports all common file types locally. Is's most powerful ability is cutting/joining videos without re-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pay. then "AVS Video Remake" is best choice for Novice Users. This software is awesome if you are concerned about the Output Quality. I have tried many, but I found AVS Video Remake is the Best One.