# Software for cutting/resizing/joining videos?

Tags: windows-vista, conversion, resolution, video-editing

I need a **free** software for **Windows Vista** that can *split* my videos, *merge* them and *resize* the resolution. These are the features I need. Features like *conversion* from one format to another would be useful but not necessary.

Any cool small piece of software that comes to mind??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the accepted answer (and the others) for ["What is the best software to split and joiv .avi files"](https://superuser.com/questions/9048/what-is-the-best-software-to-split-and-join-avi-files):

> On Windows, [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) should be able to do this. Check out [this guide](http://www.dvd-guides.com/content/view/13/59/) for in-depth guide on how to split videos.
>
> The creatively named [Easy Video Splitter](http://www.doeasier.org/splitter/help.html) can apparently do the job easier, but I have never used it so i would not know first hand.

Comment: If you are going to do this, can you please make it easier for everyone by including a quote from the page you are linking to, just like I have done?

Comment: VirtualDub is cool!

Answer (score 1):

I think [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) ([direct download link](http://www.erightsoft.info/GetFile.php?SUPERsetup.exe)) meets most of your needs. It can definitely convert your video's to various formats. I think it also supports splitting and resizing.

For more advanced stuff you can use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/), although that one doesn't support a lot of formats.

Comment: fretje, if you link to Super, you should also provide a direct download link, their website is plain disgraceful. shame, because it is truly a fine conversion tool. what were they thinking? :)

Comment: nothing about SUPER is user friendly. it does a great job but its so dense its painful.

Comment: @Molly: your wish has been granted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Avidemux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avidemux). It's open source and runs on Windows Vista. It's also very simple to use and supports all the formats I ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

[HJSlit](http://www.hjsplit.org/) works great & free:

> HJSplit is a popular freeware program to split and recombine files.
>   The program is available on Windows, Linux and a variety of other
>   platforms.
>
> Why should one want to split and recombine files? For instance, think
>   of a file of 50 Mb, and try to send it to a friend, post it in a
>   newsgroup or upload it to a Website or FTP server. It is usually
>   easier to send/receive, upload/download smaller parts than handle the
>   entire file in one go.
>
> HJSplit can also be useful for backups. A file of e.g. 10 gigabytes in
>   size can be split into smaller parts which then can be burned to CD's,
>   DVDs, copied to USB sticks or uploaded to an online backup service.
>
> HJSplit for Windows and Linux support file sizes of over 100
>   Gigabytes, MD5 checksums, file-compare, "run without install" and both
>   editions are fully portable.

[image]