# Good video joiner?

Tags: windows-vista

I'm looking for a good video joiner to join to avi files or any other type of files.

Free or paid.

Using a PC Windows-Vista

Comment: If you associate your SO and SU accounts you'll keep ownership of questions if they get migrated between the site.

Comment: Question has been answred here http://superuser.com/questions/66201/best-software-to-join-two-avi-files-together and here http://superuser.com/questions/9048/what-is-the-best-software-to-split-and-join-avi-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Easy Video Joiner](http://goo.gl/bLsh)

It has a GUI, to make it simpler

Answer (score 2):

**[SUPER ©](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)** (Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer) does that too ...

```
 A GUI to FFmpeg, MEncoder, MPlayer, x264, musepack,
 monkey's audio, true audio, wavpack, ffmpeg2theora
 and the theora/vorbis RealProducer plugIn.
```

**Input Video formats**: 3gp, 3g2, amv, asf, avi, dat, dvr-ms, fli, flc, flv, m2ts, mpg, mkv, mov, m4v, mp4, nsv, ogm, qt, rm(vb), str, swf, ts, trp, ty, ty+, tmf, viv, vob, wmv ..

> Any supported input Multimedia file
>   can be processed:
>
> **Join Format-Identical Files.**
>
> Mux Video & Audio Streams.
>
> DeMux Extract Streams.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/).

Comment: why a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

[FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or [MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html).

Both free, both open source. Both available on windows or Linux.

Unfortunately both are command line, but there are GUI's available if you google around.

For MEncoder, the command line would be something like:

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -o "joined.avi" "1.avi" "2.avi"
```

([source](http://howto.gumph.org/content/joining-movie-clips/))