# Codec Problems with trying to edit videos with VirtualDub

Tags: windows-7, video, 64-bit, codec, virtualdub

So, I'm a little frustrated.  According to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/9048/what-is-the-best-software-to-split-and-join-avi-files) and various other internet sources, virtualdub is supposed to allow users to quickly split and join video files.

I am using windows 7 64 Bit and the latest version of VirtualDub (64-bit).  I have tried to edit various movie files, and each attempt at editing various files I have done has not worked for me.

1. AVI file *A.avi* won't load, saying that it can't located the Decompressor for the *"FMP4"* format. I have tried [this solution](http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/621396) and [this one](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/277053-Cut-FMP4), and neither of them work.  I have tried setting the VFW Decompressor for *'Other MPEG4'* setting to XVID or LIBAVCODEC.  There is no change in Virtual Dub.
2. AVI file *C.avi* will load in Virtual Dub, but any attempt to split it gives me an error that I don't have XVID codecs installed.  I've attempted to install the proper codecs (Shark's Windows 7 Codecs, CCCP) with no change.
3. AVI file *C.avi* will load, and it will split, but won't split using the *"Direct Stream Copy"* claiming the compression algorithm is incompatible.  I tried the *"Fast Recompress"* option and it created a 27GB file out of what was supposed to be about a 300-400MB file.

Can someone please give me some insight into what I'm messing up?

Comment: Seriously, where are all the people that recommend virtual dub?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Install VLC Media Player (which will install various codecs).

Comment: I already have VLC installed, but just for kicks, i reinstalled it. No help.

Comment: Wish I could be of further help; sorry I can't be. Did you try contacting the VirtualDub support team or if they have forums posting their or searching them?

Comment: Thanks for trying.  I looked on their forums, and it says install this, install that.  I've installed, and reinstalled all their codecs.   why can't it be easy?

Comment: VLC doesn't install system codecs; its codecs are all internal.  its codec libraries might be used directly by other programs, but aren't usable via DirectShow or VFW or other windows A/V subsystems.

Answer (score 1):

You nay need to install both divx and xvid codecs.
For editing avis without quality loss, you may use camstudio free codec to encode while editing stage, them, till the final export in an more adecuate format (flv, mp4 with .h264, etc)
http://camstudio.org
(Oh, and sooner or later I end up needing to install FFDShow in the system, too, for several codecs matters...)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a codec pack. [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) is great for this. You can decide which ones, how they're installed, etc. The installer gives options for those doing video editing (as you are), and should provide you with the necessary codecs. I have yet to have a problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't install more than one codec pack they conflict, I suggest to uninstall all codec packs and codecs, then install the lastest version of K-Lite Codec Pack (it contains a very recent version of ffdshow) from here: http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm
Unistall the previous version (if you have one installed) before install and select "Reset all settings to their defaults" during the installation.
If it detect broken codecs during installation, remove them.

Then go on start menu => all programs => K-Lite Codec Pack => Configuration => ffdshow VFW interface => Decoder => Codecs => Other MPEG4 => try with both Xvid and libavcodec

Also be sure to use the latest version of VirtualDub: 1.9.10

If it still doesn't work upload the video somewhere so I can try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another thread dealing with this problem : [FMP4 codec with virtualdub](http://www.moviecodec.com/video-codecs/fmp4-codec-with-virtualdub-45814/).

The advice there is to install [ffdshow](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/FFDShow.htm), ensuring that VFW Interface does specify libavcodec (rather than XVID) for "Other MPEG4".

Comment: I've done this, did not help the situation

Answer (score 0):

I know Im too late to answer this, but there is another solution to your problem. What you are tying to do is joining and trans-coding video files right ?

If that is your need then why use virtual dub ? There is "Kirara Encoder" which includes all the codecs with itself. No need to install anything extra.

If you still want to stick to VDub then first uninstall it, then run Ccleaner(Very important), now download x64 bit codecs and install them. Do not install Klite Codec Pack. Install individual codecs separately - like xvid from xvids website - http://www.xvid.org/Downloads.15.0.html, h.264 from - http://www.h264encoder.com/ etc.

Installing codecs seperately will certainly solve your problem (As it did solved mine)