# Batch-split many AVIs in 2 parts?

Tags: video-conversion, video-editing, avi

how can I batch split many AVIs into 2 parts,
with no conversion?

NB: this didn't help much [What is the best software to split and join avi files?](https://superuser.com/questions/9048/what-is-the-best-software-to-split-and-join-avi-files)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want all the videos to be split at the ten-minute mark:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -t 00:10:00 -c copy output1.avi \
-ss 00:10:00 -c copy output2.avi
```

On systems with a bash (or other unix-based) shell, you can use a for loop to convert every *.avi in a directory (you can also do this on Windows, but I don't know how):

```
for f in *.avi; do \
ffmpeg -i "$f" -t 00:10:00 -c copy "${f/.avi/-t10.avi}" \
-ss 00:10:00 -c copy "${f/.avi/-ss10.avi}"; done
```

You may have some issues using `-c copy` with -ss: you may be best solved re-encoding the video. See the [x264 encoding guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) and the [AAC encoding guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for more information on that.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't worked with .avi for ages but [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) might be what you are after - and it [supports scripting](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=tutorial:scripting_tutorial) for iterating through a directory of .avi's (for example)

Answer (score 1):

Virtualdub [seems to get the job done easy](http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/cut_avi_with_virtualdub.cfm) - enjoy

Apparently VD has a batch mechanism and a tool exists to automatically create jobs from "templates", didn't try it myself but give it a try:
http://www.dynatec.at/techblog/dubjobs-the-virtualdub-batch-job-maker

Comment: thanks, but how do I batch-split many AVIs at the same time?

Comment: sorry didn't see that you asked for batch ... edited my answer