# How to batch cut avi files to a certain length?

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg

**The problem**

I have a folder containing approximately 1000 .avi video files, which should be split to 1 sec long film clips or alternatively cut at a certain point (say between 7 sec and 8 sec) to a length of 1 sec. These film clips contain moving particles and the program I use to measure the speed of these particles requires 1 sec long film clips. The beginning and the end of the .avi files are corrupt, so I want to take the 1 sec clip from somewhere in the middle. I want to keep the file names, as they are references for video samples I have taken. I am working on Windows 7 and have absolutely no back-ground in programming (apart from R), so treat me as a newbie.

**Earlier trials**

I been trying to find a solution for this problem for a long time. The first time I did this, I manually cut about 1000 clips with Final Cut Pro. This took me couple of days, but I do not have access to the software. Anyway, I figured that there must be a better solution. I tried to understand [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/), but got overwhelmed and gave up. Now I have been looking if FFmpeg could be the solution. I am pretty sure that it could, but I am overwhelmed again. I found this [BASH script](http://grapsus.net/blog/post/A-script-for-splitting-videos-using-ffmpeg) and @evilsoup's answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/448037/batch-split-many-avis-in-2-parts). If I could manage to combine these two, this could work. I have so many questions about this process that it is better I keep it concise:

How to combine these two scripts (splitting and for loops) in FFmpeg under Windows 7?

(i.e. can I use BASH script under windows? If yes, how?)

Comment: By your title, it sounds like you want to recombine the split files.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I just want to cut 1 sec film clip somewhere from the middle of each file (beginning and end are corrupt). I need these clips for another program to analyse speeds of particles in film clips. Sorry for ambiguity. I guess I have to edit the question a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need any complicated script.

This simple Bash loop will take every `.avi` file, skip 5 seconds into the video, cut one second (`-t 1`) from it, and write to `-cut.avi`. It will copy the video stream and discard the audio.

```
for i in *.avi; do ffmpeg -ss 5 -i "$i" -c:v copy -an -t 1 "${i%.avi}-cut.avi"; done
```

You can replace `"${i%.avi}-cut.avi"` with `"output/$i"` to write the output files to the folder `output` instead without changing their name.

You can use Bash on Windows [with Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), but this loop should be easy to translate into a Windows-native one (if anyone knows that, feel free to edit this post).

Notes for the video:

- FFmpeg is [available as a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for every major OS – it can be installed just be extracting the downloaded archive.
- If you want a more accurate starting point for cutting, consider placing the `-ss` behind `-i "$i"`.
- If the video files are damaged at the beginning, and FFmpeg can't decode the input, this might not work altogether.

Comment: Thank you @slhck. It works kind of, but I get output files that are 23 KB in size and they do not seem to contain video (at least I can't see it, when I play it). Here is the output I get from Cygwin (for one video clip): http://pastebin.com/BLMfjtLV

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that I gave you a wrong flag. Typo there. Replace `-vn` with `-an`. `-vn` disables video, while `-an` disables audio. Try it again with that :)

Comment: Works like a charm! You have just solved a major issue I have had in finishing my PhD thesis on time. Words are not enough to express my gratitude.

Comment: No worries… I'm glad to help out. Good luck with your thesis!